# Processing input file and producing output with the help of lookup file

Tags: bash

I have file in following format:

data file:

```
abcd,999,dsdsdsd
sdfsddf,389,dsfdsfs
sdsfff,356,sdfdgrh
```

lookup file:

```
code        info1       info2
389             data1           data2
356             data3           data4
999             data5           data6
```

I want the output in the format

```
abcd 999-dsdsdsd  data1, data2
sdfsddf 389-dsfdsfs  data3, data4
sdsfff 356-sdfdgrh  data5, data6
```

How do I do this with bash?

The restriction is on length on numeric data, it will of size 3 and also on last values in csv (its of size 7).

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: It looks to me like you only want to output the two file contents side by side. Am I wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't the first line be `abcd 999-dsdsdsd  data5, data6` ?